# Validation loss or model evaluate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a Gated Reccurent unit (GRU) model and I made two versions of it each are slightly different. When I ran both, Version 1 gave me a  validation mean squared error (MSE) of 0.0013, while Version 2 gave me 0.0015. This means Version 1 is a better model. But when I ran `model.evaluate(X_test,y_test)` with the test dataframe, Version gave me an MSE value of 0.0027 while Version 2 gave me 0.0018.

My question is which version is considered better, the version which gives a better Validation MSE or the model that gave a lower MSE when using the Test dataframe for predicting

Thank you.

Comment: what is size of your validation and test dataset?As per I know that you can't be sure that if the model work well on the validation data it will work well on test data.There may be reason such the validation and test data may come from different data distribution

Comment: validation is 1 million samples, and test which comes from a different dataframe is about 1million samples as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can not cheat on the test set, and choose the model so that it gives the best results on the test. Validation is meant to be used for that intention, and the test is only there to check validation and test are getting along each other.

You did not mention the size of the training, validation, and test. The size of the data you use is very important to be as big enough to represent the real distribution of the data, in training, validation, and the test.

On the other hand, the way you sample the data should be done in a way, that three sets have the same distribution.

Last, by not least, you are comparing two results which differ about 0.0002 in MSE. I do not believe it gives you good judgment on which one is better.

Comment: Actually, both GRU models are exactly the same even the train,split,and test data. The only differnece is that for one model the dataframes were filtered assuming 10% of the data are outliers, the other assumes 15%. The Train and validation dataframe come from 1 dataframe and consists of about 9million samles and 1 million samples, while the test dataset is different dataframe and also consisrs of 1 million samples.

Comment: So that can explain why test and validation differs in results. It is very possible that your validation is not a good representative for the whole distribution, which might not be very important in your case. but again, the error you get in the validation does not offer any of two models any big difference. So whether you can repeat the whole both process ten times with ten different random samplings for train and valid and then check which one generalize better in average

Comment: Indeed, I ran each code about 2-3 times for each now and took the average val MAE and MSE losses so I can fairly compare them.